# Set className for Menu KendoReact

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, kendo-react-ui

I'm working on React project that's using Kendo. For `Menu` component

> import { Menu, MenuItem } from "@progress/kendo-layout-react-wrapper";

we cannot set `className` to that control. So what is the right way to apply css for it?

I'm covering it by a  with className the using nested css to set css for that like this:

tsx:

```
<div className="menu-container">
        <Menu select={this.onSelect}>
        </Menu>
      </div>
```

css:

```
 .menu-container{
        .k-menu:not(.k-context-menu){
            background-color: #2f4f90;
            &:hover{
                background-color: #2b6ebd;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use [ReactDOM findDOMNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) and [DOM elements' classList property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). You could put this inside you component:

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).classList.add('MyClass');
}
```

There is also a [native Kendo React Menu which is better supported](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/layout/menu/). You should be able to use the same approach for it.

Comment: You mention about 'kendo-react-layout', right? It still don't have className for Menu component, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Unfortunately, it does not have 'className' prop. Still, it has 'style' prop.